# link config files

Tags: configuration, symlink, ln, dot-files, nvim

### Problem

I'm trying to move my config files **from** a `.dotfiles` folder, and link those files to the corresponding config path.

### Example

In this example I'm trying

```
$ ln -s ~/.dotfiles/nvim/init.vim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

And the program (`nvim` in this case), the config file doesn't take effect.

But when I copy the file instead of linking

```
$ cp ~/.dotfiles/nvim/init.vim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

It does take effect.

### Other example

When I do the same thing but with my `.zshrc` file

```
ln -s .dotfiles/zsh/.zshrc ~/.zshrc
```

It takes effect...

### Question

How could I link my `.dotfiles` config files to the according path for config?

---

Thanks

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean _exactly_?

Comment: The program I'm trying to config doesn't consider the file.
So when I open `nvim`, I don't get the config I've added if I used a symlink, but when I copy the config file, it does.

Comment: I really can't recreate this. Neovim is quite happy to read a symbolic link as its init file.

Comment: Did you, by mistake, _quote_ the link target (`~/.dotfiles/nvim/init.vim`) when you created the link?  This would make `~` not expand, and the link would not be able to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to put .dotfiles to git repo and instead of files you end up with symlinks inside git.

There are multiple ways to handle this:

1. You probably might want to move actual files to .dotfiles and create a symlink to those in original place. Should work in most cases, but you might run into issues if there are some strange checks implemented in software which uses this configuration files (but shouldn't really happen). I'd try this one.
2. Use hardlinks instead of softlinks. `ln ~/.dotfiles/nvim/init.vim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim` instead of `ln -s`. However that might be a bit harder to track and manage. Note that hardlinks do not work for directories.
3. You might wanna try to play with bind mounts, however it works for directories only and isn't that obvious. Plus requires system changes to make this option survive reboot.

Comment: I edited the first part of the question that was wrong.

I ment to say **from** my `.dotfiles` folder. So I think I would be doing the first option you shared.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by itself...

I specified the absolute path from `~`. Like:

```
$ ln -s ~/.dotfiles/nvim/init.vim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
```

I think I was creating the symlink with a relative path before

---

Thanks everyone who answered

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ln -s ~/.dotfiles/nvim/init.vim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim`

you can also do:

`cd ~/.config/nvim`

and then

`ln -s ../../.dotfiles/nvim/init.vim` (relative)

or

`ln -s ~/.dotfiles/nvim/init.vim` (expanded to absolute)

Like this you have more control. Both rel. and abs. should work. Difference is when you copy or move.